# Difference between "to ignore sth." and "to live up to sth."

Tags: meaning-in-context, synonyms, vocabulary

I've got a question referring to the following sentences:

1. If you do not do as you are told, you **do not live up to** your teachers' or parents' orders.

and

2. If you do not do as you are told, you **ignore** your teachers' or parents' orders.

Is there a real difference in the meaning of both sentences from the perspective of a native speaker?

Is sentence 1) definitely wrong from the perspective of a native speaker?

Thanks for your help!
Best regards,
Thomas

Comment: One situation can meet two or more criteria without those criteria being identical.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a real difference between the two, to a native speaker. Sentence #1 is not idiomatic (and so a native speaker would not use it); the idiom is "living up to zzz's *expectations*". There is a quite a difference between disobeying a direct order and not living up to expectations; although the latter may include direct disobedience, it usually refers to making bad choices freely (for example: a college student who fails his courses due to partying rather than studying has not lived up to his parents' expectations).

Answer (score 0):

*Orders* can be ignored or followed, not ‘lived up to’. You  live up to *expectations*, for example. Sentence 2 is okay. Sentence 1 as written is definitely wrong. It should look like ‘you don’t follow your teachers’ orders’.